# React PromiseAll or await not "pausing" as expected

Tags: reactjs, async-await, promise

I have a object I am iterating through and making an axios call per iteration.  The following two bits of code are what I have attempted.  In one I am using an `async` function, and using `await` --  In the other, I am using a `promises` array and using `Promise.all(promises)` to iterate.  They both have the same outcome .. The axios call is sending out 1,000 plus calls all at once, and not "waiting" or "pausing".  What am I not seeing?

This is my `async` version.

```
function importProjects() {
    Object.keys(importFiles).map(async function (key) {
        await api.post(apiUrl() + "api/v2/addPin/",
            {pin: importFiles[key]})
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
        });
    });
}
```

This is my Promise version.

```
function importProjects() {
   let promises = [];
   Object.keys(importFiles).map(function (key) {
       promises.push(
           api.post(apiUrl() + "api/v2/addPin/", {
               pin: importFiles[key]
           })
       );
   });
   Promise.all(promises)
       .then(response =>
           console.log(response.data)
       );
}
```

Why to both versions send all my requests simultaneously?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) (appliies to `map` too, it runs the promises in parallel with no good way to await their completion. `Promise.all` also runs everything in parallel with a good way to await completion, but if you don't want parallel, use a plain `for .. of` loop as described in the dupe suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, `.map()` is iterating over all of the keys in the object.  The result of that iteration is to invoke that callback to `.map()` on every element, and invoking the callback performs the AJAX operation.  *Internally* that callback may be fully prepared to await, but nothing is awaiting the callback *itself*.

In the second case, `Promise.all` awaits all of the promises, not each individual one in turn.

Take a step back...

If the goal is to iterate over a collection and, one at a time, await an operation then why not just use a simple loop?  Nesting callbacks is just over-complicating things.

```
async function importProjects() {
  const keys = Object.keys(importFiles);
  for (const key of keys) {
    const response = await api.post(apiUrl() + "api/v2/addPin/", {pin: importFiles[key]});
    console.log(response.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a much more understandable method.  Just because I am using react doesn't mean I have to overthink my JS.  This perfectly suits my needs!